# Bash script error: 'which' command not found

Tags: bash, centos

The context of my question is a Silverstripe bash script that I'm trying to execute on a Centos 8 OS shell environment. The script is called sake and the relevant code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if ! [ -x "$(command -v which)" ]; then
    echo "Error: sake requires the 'which' command to operate." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Executing this, either with or without sudo privilege always results in the following error:

```
Error: sake requires the 'which' command to operate.
```

My path is:

```
echo $PATH
/home/hl/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin:/home/hl/.local/bin:/home/hl/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

`which` exists:

```
whereis which
which: /usr/bin/which /usr/share/man/man1/which.1.gz /usr/share/info/which.info.gz
```

I've tried setting a `which` alias in .bash_profile to `/usr/bin/which`, but the alias is the same as the command itself, so this was merely an act of desperation.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try "which which" rather than "whereis".  Maybe it's not executable.

Comment: also check what `command -v which` and `command -V which` print out from inside your shell. It's likely an alias by default on centos.

Comment: Debug it systematically: First do a `/usr/bin/which which`. Do you get an error message? If yes, what is it?